# Internal Graphics Display Recognition

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11, intel

I would like to connect my TV as a fourth screen to my PC (running Windows-11) via HDMI. My three main screens are connected to the graphics card (RTX 2070). The TV is connected to the graphics unit of the processor (i9-9900k) via the motherboard.

The problem is: my PC only recognises the TV as a screen if the TV was switched on during the boot process. If the TV is switched on after booting, it is not recognised as a display. Since I only want to use the TV sometimes, I don't always switch it on before starting the PC. Restarting every time I need it is a work around but not optimal.

Does anyone have an idea what causes this behaviour and if there is a solution?
(I have already tested the behaviour with another (real PC monitor) and the behaviour is the same here. So I assume that it is not due to the HDMI connection or the TV).

Comment: Likely the internal graphics is disabled when booting and no display is detected so that it doesn't waste power. No point leaving it enabled if it's likely to be unused. You might have an option for disabling ntegrated graphics in your BIOS, chances are you want to set it to "always on" rather than "auto"

Comment: @Mokubai that did the trick. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Converted to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the internal graphics is disabled when booting and no display is detected so that it doesn't waste power. No point leaving it enabled if it's unlikely to be used.

In your BIOS you might have an option for disabling integrated graphics, if available you want to set it to "always on" rather than "auto".